# Error in saving Random Forest Classifier model in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("label")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, rf])
model = pipeline.fit(training) 
model.save(sc, '<path_to_save>')
```

I am trying to save the model file by using the above code.But getting an unexpected error -

```
TypeError: save() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I don't understand this error. I am passing 2 arguments only but still getting this error.
Do anybody have idea? What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this is working. But removing 1st field 'sc' works for me.

```
model.save('<path_to_save>')
```

I am able to save the model file by this command.

Comment: Why puzzled? This is the correct way, according to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.save). Also, you are obviously referring to Spark ML, and not to MLlib (tag edited).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and it is not working! any thoughts?